# Including URI of a jpeg HeightMap file from a directory other than the one given

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi

I am new to Gazebo, and am stuck on this problem. I couldn't find a way out of this. The solution may be simple, but nothing is working from the top of my mind.

I have created my own jpeg HeightMap file and it is stored in "/home/$userName/Desktop/new_terrain.jpg". I have to use the file from this directory instead of the default one i.e. "GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH/medai/materials/textures/", where all texture files are saved. I already have the HeightMap thing working if I copy new_terrain.jpg file into the default folder.

I exported the the new path using bash command, but it didn't work out. Is there a way we can define the URI such that the xml file extracts the image from the specified directory. Could you suggest a solution?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3570/including-uri-of-a-jpeg-heightmap-file-from-a-directory-other-than-the-one-given/) by [OxyGen](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/419/oxygen/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-07-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Where do you store the other texture files such as `dirt_diffuse_specular.png`, and how are you exporting `GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH`?

Assuming `new_terrain.jpg` is on Desktop, and `dirt_diffuse_specular.png` is the one located in default resource folder, then just export:

`export GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH=/home/yourusername/Desktop:$GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH`

---

Originally posted by [iche033](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/58/iche033/) with karma: 1018 on 2013-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [OxyGen](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/419/oxygen/) on 2013-07-15**:
Thanks. That is what I did. As i described in my answer, it works when we mention the URI for new_terrain.jpg, but doesn't work for other texture files like dirt_diffuse_terrain.jpg or dirt_normal.jpg. Anyways, thanks for your help. At least this confirms that I was on the right track.